# Regarding grep command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I am trying to change the copyright headers in my assignment. I was able to list all the files with the copyright headers by using following commmand:

```
    grep -rni copyright *
```

By the above command, I got around 1000 files.

Can anyone please help me how to change all the files in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will apply a text change to files with the word "copyright" in them (case insensitive):

```
for filename in *; do
  if grep -qi "copyright" "$filename"; then
    sed -i'' -e 's/old text/new text/' "$filename"
  fi
done
```

Note that this only works on the *current* directory.  To handle files in subdirectories, you'll probably want to use the `find` command.

If you can describe the text change you want to make, we may be able to suggest more precise methods to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -ril copyright * | xargs sed -i 's/old text/new text/'
```

Comment: Is the text to be changed in the filenames, or in the body of the files?

Comment: @ghoti, using xargs means the filenames found by "grep -l" will be passed as arguments to sed.

Comment: @glennjackman - When I left my comment, there was no `xargs` in his command line, as you'll see in the change history.  Note that this solution still suffers from the [Parsing LS problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple tool called [headache](http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/headache/manual.html) I've found quite useful for dealing with this sort of problem.  Available on [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=headache&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=headache&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) at least.